# ScrollTo working in nav but need it for all hrefs

Tags: javascript, scroll, anchor, href, smooth-scrolling

I have scrollTo nested inside the template I'm working from. I can't seem to get it to point to my other anchor links (works fine from the nav bar and scroll to top).

My inclination is to do this to make it universal across the site:

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTo() > 100) {
  $('.header').fadeIn('slow');
} else {
  $('.element2').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

});

```
$('.body, a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({scrollTo : 0},1200);
return false;
});
```

Comment: You can select elements with href attr: $("a[href]");

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way to list multiple hrefs and make the nav exempt?  It has its own scroll functions? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well. 
You want to animate your page whenever you click any element that is NOT nav.

You could do this.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
var targetElem = $(event.target);
if(!targetElem.is("nav")){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTo : 0},1200);
    return false;
 }
});
```